# Find and replace cells with asterisk, *

Tags: r, regex, replace, gsub

I have a dataframe where some of the cells contain * values.

```
RowNumber Col1
1         *
2         **
3         A123
4         ****
5         123
```

I am trying to replace these * values with blank/empty values

Desired Output

```
RowNumber Col1
1         
2         
3         A123
4         
5         123
```

Any advise on accomplishing this is much appropriated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `regex` to replace the `*` with blanks (`""`).  The `*` is a metacharacter representing zero or more characters.  So, we need to escape it (`\\*`), or place it inside square brackets (`[*]`) to read it as the literal `*` character`

```
df1$Col1 <- gsub("[*]+", "", df1$Col1)
df1$Col1
#[1] ""     ""     "A123" ""     "123"
```

Or use the `fixed=TRUE` argument

```
gsub("*", "", df1$Col1, fixed = TRUE)
```